# Existence of Deuterium peroxide

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, stability, structural-formula

Does deuterium peroxide exist? Wikipedia has no reference. Also, the sites for delivery of chemicals like "Pubchem" or "Chemspider" have no reference.

In my book, a preparation of $\ce{D2O2}$ is given,

$$\ce{K2S2O8 + 2D2O -> 2KDSO4 +D2O2}$$

If $\ce{D2O2}$ exist, what are its physical properties (structure and appearance etc.)?

Comment: It does exist. A quick SciFinder search brings up around 50 papers, mostly dealing with rotational/vibrational spectra - don't know if larger quantities have been prepared. As for the structure: it's pretty similar to that of hydrogen peroxide, but has a slightly shorter O-D distance. Here is a reference for its [structure](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022285277903319).

Comment: It's simply deuterated H2O2 so of course it exists and is quite similar.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It does exist. At least Google shows one supplier situated in [New Jersey](http://www.iconisotopes.com/code/ShowPDF.asp).

> ID 1130   Deuterium Peroxide (30% in D2O) D2O2    98  5   5.0g / 10.0g

Though for some reason I could not find any reputable supplier like Cambridge Isotopes or Sigma-Aldrich (strange!). As far as physical properties are concerned, as pointed out by @snurden there exists a significant amount of literature. Here is one article from the [Canadian Journal of Chemistry](http://dx.doi.org/10.1139/v51-022) that includes study of many properties (behind a pay wall though).

Abstract:

[image: Abstract of above paper]

And to answer final part of your question:
[image: Result of same paper]